# vue returns not defined error when I try to use axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to use axios i defined it with `windows.axios` and i want to  get api but it returns error and tells me that axiot is not defined

```js
<script>
window.axios = require('axios');
export default {
  name: 'app',
  mounted: function() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you should be using it like this:

```js
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        mounted: function() {
            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        }
    };
</script>
```